# How to display m3u8 video to canvas in Safari?

Tags: canvas, video, safari, m3u8

An m3u8 video file loaded to `<video>` tag by using the hls.js plugin. It works well now.
And then I was going to display it to `<canvas>`.

```
<canvas id='viewport' width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<video id="video" controls crossorigin="anonymous" preload="auto"></video>

<script>
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var videoSrc = './Downloads/842x480/video.m3u8';

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
        hls.attachMedia(video);

        hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        });

    }
</script>
```

It worked on other browsers well except for Safari.
Is there a way to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/ FWIW, even loading an HLS source directly causes the same issue (because yes, Safari does have native support for HLS).

Comment: Found https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186038